# Class::DBI - does it load all tables?

Tags: profiling, perl, class-dbi

We have a MySQL database with very big number of tables. Unfortunately in 2018 we still use Perl CGI. So loading time of a script is essential.

`DBIx::Class` was ruled out by me because it loads about 1.6 sec (so long because it loads Perl definitions for *all* tables of the DB) what is clearly too much.

How quickly `Class::DBI` loads? My main question: Does Perl load information about all available tables (like `DBIx::Class` does) when we use `Class::DBI` or does it load Perl definitions for only these tables which we actually use?

---

The following is a `DBIx::Class` code which loads 1.6 sec:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package MyApp::Schema;
use lib '.../ORMs/dbix-class';
use base qw/DBIx::Class::Schema/;

__PACKAGE__->load_namespaces();

1;
```

(The schema is autogenerated.)

Is there any way to make it faster? How to use it without loading all tables?

Comment: Why not switch to Fast CGI? With minimal effort, that 1.6s becomes irrelevant

Comment: It might be useful if you showed us the code you were using with DBIx::Class that was too slow.  There are different ways to initialise DBIx::Class with your schema info and it's not necessary to load all tables.  You can also set up static definitions for just the tables you care about which should load more quickly.

Comment: @ikegami if they are on a shared hosting environment they likely can't do that.

Comment: @GrantMcLean Please explain how to initialize `DBIx::Class` without loading all tables. I've edited the question

Answer (score 2):

I really wouldn't recommend [Class::DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::DBI). It's been unmaintained for twelve years - and there were good reasons why everyone switched to [DBIx::Class](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class).

I would highly recommend working on the problem that leads to you still using CGI. What is preventing you from, for example, using [CGI::Emulate::PSGI](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Emulate::PSGI) to trivially convert your CGI code to PSGI apps which you can then deploy in a persistent environment like FastCGI or, better, as a standalone service which you can then access using nginx? Any of these solutions would mean that the DBIx::Class load time is no longer problem.

Obviously, I have no idea what is keeping you tied to CGI. But, in my experience, moving to PSGI solution is often easier than people expect it to be and it will undoubtedly leave you in a better position.