# Use DBIx::Class without loading all tables

Tags: dbix-class, perl

They [say](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51070019/856090) in comments that `DBIx::Class` can be used without loading all tables.

How to use `DBIx::Class` without loading all tables? (I need this for performance reasons.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way might be to use [`load_classes()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Schema#load_classes) instead of [`load_namespaces()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Schema#load_namespaces).

But you never explained why you think you can't switch to a persistent environment where this load time wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I would switch, my boss doesn't

Comment: @porton: What reasons does he give?

Comment: Finally he  agreed to use FastCGI, so we can use `DBIx::Class`

Comment: @porton: That's the wrong approach as you'll need to rewrite stuff. But at least it's better than where you are now

Comment: @Dave Cross, hum? When we switched to FastCGI, we simply used a wrapper. We didn't need to rewrite a thing.

Comment: @ikegami: It's likely I'm misremembering then. It's such a long time since I went from CGI to FastCGI. I remember it being incredibly difficult.